Can you help me identify which animal this bone belongs to?

I found this interesting bone on the shore of Lefkada in the Ionian sea. I can’t find a similar bone to determine which animal it belongs to, nor can I determine whether it’s from a terrestrial or a marine animal. On the bottom side there was also a brownish gooey substance, but I don’t know it it was decomposed meat or just something else that stuck to it. I thought it was maybe from a caretta caretta but their skeleton is different. As for substance, it felt and looked like a bone, it definitely wasn’t a plant.

What about this specimen makes you think that it's not C. caretta? It looks a lot like a hyoplastron to me. For comparison, see https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Specimens-of-Caretta-caretta-Left-dorsal-carapace-view-and-right-ventral-plastron_fig3_340649642

Looks like a holdfast, probably from a seaweed, to me.

Could you edit to give some idea of scale? Don't suppose that you've a picture in profile, and from below? Maybe a close-up of the surface structure. Can you describe the texture and flexibility of the fringes - were they bone-rigid or softer?

Based on the shape, the location, and the fact that the OP is confident that the specimen is bone and not plant material, this appears to be the hyoplastron of Caretta caretta, the Loggerhead Sea Turtle. The Ionian Sea is in the range of the Loggerhead, with nesting sites on the southern coast of Italy and Southwestern Greece.
I have outlined the specimen in red, for comparison with the hyoplastron outline from Yudha et al (2020) (numbered 10 in their figure). The shape is a very close match. The hyoplastron of the Hawksbill Sea Turtle (also in Yudha et al. 2020) is also a near-match, but the Hawksbill is not thought to occur in the Ionian Sea.


I'd say based on what we've got, this fits perfectly.
